# Swipe gesture instead of backbarbuttonitem with UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer, backbarbuttonitem

I've looked around and I can't for the life of me find a way to replace the `backbarbuttonitem` with a swipe gesture. I want to swipe left and have the app revert back to the previous view controller. Just to clarify I'm using a `UINavigationController` to manage all my View Controllers. Any ideas? Or is this not possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked it out and now I feel stupid for asking this question! Here is the code I used:

I created a Swipe Gesture in the `ViewDidLoad` function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


// -- EDIT Added the allocation of a UIGestureRecognizer -- //
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotoPreviousView:)];
    swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}
```

Then I simply created this...

```
- (void)gotoPreviousView:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Easy! Looked too far into it and the answer was staring me in the face. Hopefully if you don't know how, you'll see this and not make the same rookie error I did ha...